# Multiplication of Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, stdarray

I have the following problem:

```
template< size_t... N_i >
class A
{
  // ...
  std::array< float, /* product of the unpacked elements of N_i */ > arr;
};
```

As you can see above, I try to declare an `std::array` named `arr` as a member of a class `A`. Here, I want `arr` to have the size *product of the unpacked elements of `N_i`*, e.g., in case of `A<2,3,4>`, "arr" should have the size `2*3*4=24`.
Does anyone know how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++17:

```
std::array < float, (... * N_i)> arr;
```

In C++14:

```
// outside the class
template<size_t... Ns>
constexpr size_t product(){
    size_t p = 1;
    for(auto n : { Ns... }) p *= n;
    return p;
}

// then
std::array< float, product<N_i...>()> arr;
```

In C++11:

```
template<size_t... N_i>
struct product { 
    static const size_t value = 1; 
};

template<size_t N_1, size_t... N_i>
struct product<N_1, N_i...> {
    static const size_t value = N_1 * product<N_i...>::value;
};

std::array< float, product<N_i...>::value> arr;
```

Alternatively, you can use a recursive `constexpr` function.

Comment: ... and here, on the top answer you can see the evolution of `C++`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++14 you can do this:

```
size_t v = 1;
size_t _[] = { (v = v*N_i)... };
```

As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<cstddef>

template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto f() {
    std::size_t v = 1;
    std::size_t _[] = { (v = v*I)... };
    (void)_;  // silent a warning and nothing more
    return v;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(f<2,3,4>() == 24,"!");
}
```

Your class can be defined as it follows:

```
template< size_t... N_i >
class A {
    // ...
    std::array< float, f<N_i...>()> arr;
};
```

In C++17 `fold-expressions` will simplify it.

Comment: @T.C. You are right, they were not _relaxed_. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with recursive definition of constexpr function.

And in c++14 using [variable template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) this can have cleaner look :

```
template <typename ...Ts> 
constexpr size_t product()
{
    return  1;
}
template <size_t I,size_t... Is> 
constexpr size_t product()
{
    return   I * product<Is...>();
}

template <size_t I, size_t... Is> 
constexpr size_t prod = product<I, Is...>();


template< size_t... N_i >
class A
{
    std::array< float, prod<N_i...> > arr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function in your array declaration:

```
template<typename ...Args>
constexpr int multiply(Args&&... args)
{
    return (args * ... );
}
```

It uses C++17 fold expressions, and can be included like

```
template< size_t... N_i >
class A
{
  // ...
  std::array< float, multiply(N_i ...) > arr;
};
```

Comment: ...just plug the fold expression in if you have it. Why an extra function?

Comment: sure, that's much shorter ... by about 95% :-)  Still I have the feeling that it's *slightly* better to understand and extend.